# SVN commit command line with path inside a variable in php

Tags: php, svn, cmd, tortoisesvn, commit

I need to create a web app which works with SVN command line. So I want to use a exec command with svn commit and a variable contains the path of the working copy. I tried this code but didn't work. Commit didn't take place.

```
<?php
$lpath="c:\a\svn\projectwc";
$msg="first commit";
exec("svn commit -m $msg $lpath");
?>
```

And yeah I added all the files inside already. I tried by replacing the lpath with path value and it worked. 
Please help...

Comment: Define "didn't work".

Comment: No errors were shown but commit didn't take place.

Answer (score 2):

Your string expands to

```
svn commit -m first commit c:\a\svn\projectwc
```

Whereas you need to do

```
svn commit -m "first commit" c:\a\svn\projectwc
```

As the log message is more than one word it needs to be in quotes.

I think you should re-think what you are trying to achieve here. Constructing strings based on user input and passing them to `exec` is a very bad idea from a security perspective.

Also you tagged the post tortoise-svn - if you invoke  TSVN from the command line it pops up the GUI which is definitely not appropriate server side.

Then you've got other considerations like:

- How to log error messages when things go wrong
- Does the Web server have sufficient access to the working copy to perform these operations
- Is the invocation of "svn" even possible in your environment.

Whatever you are trying to do, it's probable there is some free software out there that does it already. svn has a webdav interface and an API implemented in many languages - this would be *far* safer than using `exec`

Comment: The commit works if I specify the path directly, but not when I'm using a variable. And that interface, there's a pecl extension for SVN in PHP but the problem is that it would take about 2or 3 days to process the request and to install it in the system.( Iam doing it in a software firm so they have firewall and all that stuff). But to finish it before that iam using command line SVN. And its a school project so I wouldn't worry about the security.

Comment: Assign the command to a variable eg `$cmd = "svn commit -m \"$msg\" $lpath";`. Check it looks sane: `echo $cmd;` See also that I added quotes around your commit message here.